# Finding sum of Absolute Difference of Every pair of integer from an array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array, find the sum of the absolute difference of every pair of integers.

For example: Given `a[]= {2,3, 5, 7 };`

output would be `(3-2) + (5-2) + (7-2) + (5-3) + (7-3) + (7-5) = 17`.

It must be done better than `O(n^2)`.

The original array isn't necessarily sorted.

Comment: I know the obvious brute force solution. I was also thinking that, difference between successive numbers will appear exactly (n-1) times. But the result doesn't match with that of the brute-force solution.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

note you add each number exactly k times (where k is its place if you sort the list)

also, you subtract each number exactly n-1-k times

you can sort the list (O(nlogn)) and then iterate over the sorted array, multiplying each element as mentioned above.

Comment: Actually can't you do it in O(n) using radix or counting sort and then do the post processing as you mentioned it.

Comment: @Sumod: If the numbers are from a limited range - yes, you could use radix sort/counting sort to optimize indeed.

Answer (score 9):

I think I have found the answer. I got it by looking into the result expression in my post.

Here is the code in C++.

```cpp
    int AbsDiff(int a[], int n)
    {
      if ( n < 2 ) return 0;
      sort(a,a+n);     
      int sum = 0;
      int i;
      for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
      {
        sum += (a[i]*(i) - a[i]*(n-i-1));
      }
      return sum;
    }
```

Comment: note that sorting will be needed before you iterate over the array, otherwise you might even get a negative answer.

Answer (score 8):

> For example: Given a[]= {2,3, 5, 7 };
>   output would be (3-2) + (5-2) + (7-2) + (5-3) + (7-3) + (7-5) = 17.

I suppose you could

- Sum the multiplication of each number starting backwards with #count - 1 to get the total
- Sum the multiplication of each number starting up front with #count - 1 to get the total to subtract

This would then become `(7*3 + 5*2 +3*1) - (2*3 + 3*2 + 5*1) = 17`

Comment: Yes, the answer is based on this. I have also posted the code in replying to this question myself.

Comment: @Gunner - typical case of finding the answer when trying to explain the problem :). +1 but I feel the accepted answer should got to amit. He beat both of us to it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all array needs to be sorted in O(nlogn) time.

Now I would not give you the exact solution to this problem rather I would give you an intuition to solve this problem. 
If we try to generalize count of the number of times a particular number at index *i* is getting added and number of times it is being subtracted then for every index *i* we can use that mathematically derived formula to compute the sum of contributions of every number in the absolute difference in **O(N) time and O(1) extra space.**

You can refer to this video if you find difficulties in understanding this concept.

Video Link:- https://youtu.be/A4sz4kNDa-8

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative perspective on this.  Here is Mathematica code:

```
With[{n = Length@# - 1}, Range[-n, n, 2].Sort[#]] &
```

`n` = one less than the length of the list

`Range[-n, n, 2]` creates a list with numbers from `-n` to `n` in steps of `2`, e.g. `Range[-4, 4, 2]` = `{-4, -2, 0, 2, 4}`

`.` is vector dot product, e.g. `{a, b, c} . {x, y, z}` = `a x + b y + c z`

`Sort` is just sort.

So, for your example, we have: `{-3, -1, 1, 3} . {2, 3, 5, 7}` = `17`

Here is a plot of list length versus time:

[image]

Comment: aren't creating the ranged list and dot product both omega(n)? sorting remains in both algorithms if I understood correctly, and you actually have 2 implicit iterations over an array of size n instead of one (dot product and creating the list)

Comment: @amit I think Gunner is already doing what I was trying to illustrate, but I missed it because I don't like reading procedural code.  You are probably correct in your observations, but this is the most natural way to do something like this in Mathematica.  IMHO my graph shows that its complexity is not bad.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: of course not bad, it's O(nlogn) for sorting, but if any, it will be slower and not faster then the iterative approach.

Comment: @amit I amended the post to correct that.  I thought Gunner was doing something less efficient when I made that statement.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: no doubts, your alternative is much more elegant for math-based languages.

Comment: @amit Getting off topic, Mathematica is usually very slow compared to compiled code, but I think it might do pretty well in this case, as all the functions in play (Sort, Dot, Range) I believe to be well optimized.  How fast can you compute the result for an unsorted array of 500,000 machine size integers in your preferred language?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'll make a java code later and try it... but running benchmarks on different machines worth nothing...

Comment: @amit, I wouldn't say that.  While programs may be hundreds of times faster or slower than each other, computers usually are not.  Testing on different machines isn't useful for tiebreaking, but it can usually distinguish order of magnitude performance differences.

Comment: 100 runs for 500,000 elements (random generated at the range [0,1000000) ) finished on my machine on 101 millis/run on java

Comment: @amit thanks.  My ~=220ms on an older machine does appear competitive.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: the variance is expected to be much more platform dependent then anything, since both solutions have the same bottleneck - sorting, which for 500,000 elements is ~10,000,000 compare ops. the constant multiplyer for n is neglected compared to log(n).

Answer (score 0):

The code below calculates a[0]*(-3) + a[1]*(-1) + a[2]*(1) + a[3]*(3), if size of array = 4.

```
result := 0
for i := 0 to sizeof(a)-1 do
begin
   result := result + a[i] * (i*2 - sizeof(a) + 1)
end
```

If you need to deal with sorted array, you can sort it at first by quick sort algorithm with O(n*log(n)) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am little late to post this but I guess this CPP program should work.

```
//JUST LIKE ANIMALS !!!!

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;

ll funcy(ll a[], ll n)
{

ll sum = 0;
ll i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
sum += (a[i]*(i) - a[i]*(n-i-1));
}
return sum;
}

int main(){
ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);
ll i,n;cin>>n;ll v[n+1];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>v[i];
sort(&v[0],&v[n]);
cout<<AbsDiff(v,n);
return 0;
```

}

P.s. Provided n>2. Please if there is something wrong in this , feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this small piece of working code in **JAVA**.
Hope it helps and make sense.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PairDifference {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {2,3,5,7};
        System.out.println(getPairDifference(arr));
    }

    static int getPairDifference(int[] a){
        int diff = 0;
        Arrays.sort(a);
        int n = a.length;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            diff += (a[i]*i) - (a[n-1-i]*i);

        return diff;
    }

}
```