# Minimum sum of the difference of k pairwise elements

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to calculate the minimum sum of the difference of k elements in an array of size n and k<=n.
What I did is:
 1. Sorted the elements in increasing order
 2. If n!=k then I performed an operation
 3. else if n == k I performed another operation.

For example: n = 7
k = 3
10 100 300 200 1000 20 30

I will first sort the numbers. 10 20 30 100 200 300 1000
According to my algorithm:
 n!=k
 so first I will take 10 20 30:
 this means diff = 40
 continuing like this, 40 is the minimum value that I get.

I wanted to know if there is a better approach than this:

This is my algorithm:

```
if(n!=k)
{
 for(i = 0 ;i < n - k;i++)
 {
   diff = 0;
   l = 0;
   for(j = i;j < i + k;j++)
   {
       diff += (a[j] * l - a[j] *(k-l-1));
       if(min < diff)
           break;
       l++;
   }
   if(j == i + k && diff > 0)
       min = diff;
   //cout<<"after: "<<min<<endl; 

 }
}
else
{
    if(k == 1)
      min = a[0];
    else 
    {
        diff = 0;
        for(i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            diff+=a[i]*i - a[i]*(n-i-1);
        }
        min = diff;
    }

}
cout<<min<<endl;
```

Similar to this question: [Finding sum of Absolute Difference of Every pair of integer from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855066/finding-sum-of-absolute-difference-of-every-pair-of-integer-from-an-array)

Not for every pair, depends on k.

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean by "absolute sum of differences". Differences of what exactly? Pairwise distinct elements? `diff += (a[j] * l - a[j] *(k-l-1))` is not an absolute sum, and it is not clear what you are taking the difference between.

Comment: I am really sorry.
Yes I meant pairwise distinct elements. The array is sorted. So diff won't be negative.
So for 6 3 1 2 4 is the array, after sorting it will be 1 2 3 4 6.
In case k = 3
then (2 - 1) + (3 - 1) + (3 - 2) = 4

Comment: You need to explain your code if you expect others to improve it. For example, you need to show the derivation of your algorithm. (You did some nontrivial algebraic manipulation behind the scenes to come up with `a[j] * i - a[j] * (k-i-1)`, and somebody will think they used the same secret algebraic formula as you, then realize that it doesn't match your code for `k=1` and assume they guessed incorrectly.) Furthermore, recommendations for improving code that already works belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com, not stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I have made some edits. I hope it is clear now,

Comment: To fit better into the Q&A model, I suggest you separate out your approach from the question and post this as an answer (which you can then accept if no-one comes up with a better solution) (and also preferably add / replace it by a high-level description and/or pseudo-code, and make a complete example, rather than saying "continuing like this"). Unless you want people to suggest improvements to your code (as opposed to a completely different approach), in which case this belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482332/find-subset-with-k-elements-that-are-closest-to-eachother/19487521#19487521

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding your question correctly but it seems like the same algo as the link but you could pass by value to a function for different values of k that would sort the vector based on the k value passed in. See below.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int absDiffSum( std::vector<int> v, int k )
{
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.begin() + k);

  int n=(v.begin() + k) - v.begin();
  if ( n < 2 )
    return 0;

  int sum = 0;
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
  {
    int k = n - i - 1;
    sum+=(v[i]*i - v[i]*k);
  }

  return sum;
}


int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> v = { 2, 3, 5, 7 };

  std::cout << (3-2) + (5-2) + (7-2) + (5-3) + (7-3) + (7-5) << std::endl;
  std::cout << absDiffSum( v, 4 ) << std::endl;;

  std::cout << (3-2) + (5-2) + (5-3) << std::endl;
  std::cout << absDiffSum( v, 3 ) << std::endl;;

  std::cout << (3-2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << absDiffSum( v, 2 ) << std::endl;;
}
```