# Find subset with K elements that are closest to eachother

Tags: python, algorithm

Given an array of integers size **N**, how can you efficiently find a subset of size **K** with elements that are closest to each other?

Let the closeness for a subset (x1,x2,x3,..xk) be defined as:

[image]

```
2 <= N <= 10^5

2 <= K <= N
```

**constraints:** Array may contain duplicates and is not guaranteed to be sorted.

My brute force solution is very slow for large N, and it doesn't check if there's more than 1 solution:

```
N = input()
K = input()
assert 2 <= N <= 10**5
assert 2 <= K <= N
a = []
for i in xrange(0, N):
    a.append(input())
a.sort()

minimum = sys.maxint
startindex = 0

for i in xrange(0,N-K+1):
    last = i + K
    tmp = 0
    for j in xrange(i, last):
        for l in xrange(j+1, last):
            tmp += abs(a[j]-a[l])
            if(tmp > minimum):
                break

    if(tmp < minimum):
        minimum = tmp
        startindex = i #end index = startindex + K?
```

**Examples:**

```
N = 7
K = 3
array = [10,100,300,200,1000,20,30]
result = [10,20,30]

N = 10
K = 4
array = [1,2,3,4,10,20,30,40,100,200]
result = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: I assume it's not, but you might want to explicitly state if the array is sorted.

Comment: `a.sort()` is explicit enough for me.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be sorted

Comment: @Nima Do you have any test data that we can work with?

Comment: Maybe I didn't notice. In what metric do you measure closeness of elements in a set?

Comment: @WaleedKhan that's code, not a spec. The *question* is the spec, and it doesn't say. I stand by my request for clarification.

Comment: @Mai It looks like the sum of the differences of adjacent elements in sorted order.

Comment: @kojiro I've updated the question for your clarification.

Comment: @kojiro I didn't mean to question your statement but instead provide justification for future readers that the array isn't sorted (which is why I didn't reply with @kojiro).

Comment: @WaleedKhan I've added 2 example input/outputs.

Comment: Isn't this a question in an ongoing competition -_-

Comment: @Shashank Gupta let's hope Nima doesn't get any award from that competition, or he will be in some trouble -_-

Comment: @WaleedKhan  It's more complex than that.  It's the sum of all pairwise distances for K elements.  The OP used summation notation that represents a double sum in compact notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current solution is `O(NK^2)` (assuming `K > log N`).  With some analysis, I believe you can reduce this to `O(NK)`.

The closest set of size K will consist of elements that are adjacent in the sorted list.  You essentially have to first sort the array, so the subsequent analysis will assume that each sequence of `K` numbers is sorted, which allows the double sum to be simplified.

Assuming that the array is sorted such that `x[j] >= x[i]` when `j > i`, we can rewrite your closeness metric to eliminate the absolute value:

[image]

Next we rewrite your notation into a double summation with simple bounds:

[image]

Notice that we can rewrite the inner distance between `x[i]` and `x[j]` as a third summation:

[image]

where I've used `d[l]` to simplify the notation going forward:

[image]

Notice that `d[l]` is the distance between each adjacent element in the list.  Look at the structure of the inner two summations for a fixed `i`:

```
j=i+1         d[i]
j=i+2         d[i] + d[i+1]
j=i+3         d[i] + d[i+1] + d[i+2]
...
j=K=i+(K-i)   d[i] + d[i+1] + d[i+2] + ... + d[K-1]
```

Notice the triangular structure of the inner two summations.  This allows us to rewrite the inner two summations as a single summation in terms of the distances of adjacent terms:

```
total: (K-i)*d[i] + (K-i-1)*d[i+1] + ... + 2*d[K-2] + 1*d[K-1]
```

which reduces the total sum to:

[image]

Now we can look at the structure of this double summation:

```
i=1     (K-1)*d[1] + (K-2)*d[2] + (K-3)*d[3] + ... + 2*d[K-2] + d[K-1]
i=2                  (K-2)*d[2] + (K-3)*d[3] + ... + 2*d[K-2] + d[K-1]
i=3                               (K-3)*d[3] + ... + 2*d[K-2] + d[K-1]
...
i=K-2                                                2*d[K-2] + d[K-1]
i=K-1                                                           d[K-1]
```

Again, notice the triangular pattern.  The total sum then becomes:

```
1*(K-1)*d[1] + 2*(K-2)*d[2] + 3*(K-3)*d[3] + ... + (K-2)*2*d[K-2] 
  + (K-1)*1*d[K-1]
```

Or, written as a single summation:

[image]

This compact single summation of adjacent differences is the basis for a more efficient algorithm:

1. Sort the array, order `O(N log N)`
2. Compute the differences of each adjacent element, order `O(N)`
3. Iterate over each `N-K` sequence of differences and calculate the above sum, order `O(NK)`

Note that the second and third step could be combined, although with Python your mileage may vary.

The code:

```
def closeness(diff,K):
  acc = 0.0
  for (i,v) in enumerate(diff):
    acc += (i+1)*(K-(i+1))*v
  return acc

def closest(a,K):
  a.sort()
  N = len(a)
  diff = [ a[i+1] - a[i] for i in xrange(N-1) ]

  min_ind = 0
  min_val = closeness(diff[0:K-1],K)

  for ind in xrange(1,N-K+1):
    cl = closeness(diff[ind:ind+K-1],K)
    if cl < min_val:
      min_ind = ind
      min_val = cl

  return a[min_ind:min_ind+K]
```

Answer (score 2):

[itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to the rescue?

```
from itertools import combinations

def closest_elements(iterable, K):
    N = set(iterable)
    assert(2 <= K <= len(N) <= 10**5)

    combs = lambda it, k: combinations(it, k)
    _abs = lambda it: abs(it[0] - it[1])
    d = {}
    v = 0

    for x in combs(N, K):
        for y in combs(x, 2):
            v += _abs(y)

        d[x] = v
        v = 0

    return min(d, key=d.get)

>>> a = [10,100,300,200,1000,20,30]
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,10,20,30,40,100,200]
>>> print closest_elements(a, 3); closest_elements(b, 4)
(10, 20, 30) (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

This procedure can be done with `O(N*K)` if `A` is sorted. If `A` is not sorted, then the time will be bounded by the sorting procedure.

This is based on 2 facts (relevant only when `A` is ordered):

- The closest subsets will always be subsequent
- When calculating the closeness of `K` subsequent elements, the sum of distances can be calculated as the sum of each two subsequent elements time `(K-i)*i` where `i` is `1,...,K-1`.
- <del>When iterating through the sorted array, it is redundant to recompute the entire sum, we can instead remove `K` times the distance between the previously two smallest elements, and add `K` times the distance of the two new largest elements. this fact is being used to calculate the closeness of a subset in `O(1)` by using the closeness of the previous subset.</del>

Here's the pseudo-code

```
List<pair> FindClosestSubsets(int[] A, int K)
{
    List<pair> minList = new List<pair>;
    int minVal = infinity;
    int tempSum;
    int N = A.length;

    for (int i = K - 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        tempSum = 0;

        for (int j = i - K + 1; j <= i; j++)
              tempSum += (K-i)*i * (A[i] - A[i-1]);

        if (tempSum < minVal)
        {
              minVal = tempSum;
              minList.clear();
              minList.add(new pair(i-K, i);
        }

        else if (tempSum == minVal)
              minList.add(new pair(i-K, i);
    }

    return minList;
}
```

This function will return a list of pairs of indexes representing the optimal solutions (the starting and ending index of each solution), it was implied in the question that you want to return **all** solutions of the minimal value.

Comment: Very interesting, I will try it when I get back home and update the question.

Comment: I can't make your update step work properly when I write out the sums symbolically.  In particular, I don't see how it maintains the correct coefficients (`i*(K-i)`).  Could you elaborate on (i.e., prove) your third claim?

Comment: Yes, his third claim is false. That only works if each two subsequent element gets multiplied independent of the position, which is not the case here. For example the distance in the set `{1, 2, 10, 11}` is 38, calculated correctly by step 2. But if we shift to `{2, 10, 11, 12}`, the distance by step 3 is still 38, while it should be 31.

Comment: You're right, step 3 is incorrect. I suppose if I use step 2 again to recalculate it's pretty similar to sfstewman's answer (`O(N*K)`). if i won't think of a fix i'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
N = input()
K = input()
assert 2 <= N <= 10**5
assert 2 <= K <= N
a = some_unsorted_list
a.sort()

cur_diff = sum([abs(a[i] - a[i + 1]) for i in range(K - 1)])
min_diff = cur_diff
min_last_idx = K - 1
for last_idx in range(K,N):
    cur_diff = cur_diff - \
               abs(a[last_idx - K - 1] - a[last_idx - K] + \
               abs(a[last_idx] - a[last_idx - 1])
    if min_diff > cur_diff:
        min_diff = cur_diff
        min_last_idx = last_idx
```

From the min_last_idx, you can calculate the min_first_idx. I use range to preserve the order of idx. If this is python 2.7, it will take linearly more RAM. This is the same algorithm that you use, but slightly more efficient (smaller constant in complexity), as it does less then summing all.

Comment: This approach doesn't appear to be correct.  The definition of closeness is a summation of all pairwise differences in the tuple, which is a double summation, not a single summation of adjacent differences.  Try this approach on the array `[10,10,30,30,100,110,110,120]` with `K=4`.  The closest tuple should be `(100,110,110,120)` (closeness=60), which has smaller closeness than `(10,10,30,30)` (closeness=80).  Your approach will determine that they have the same closeness (20).

Answer (score 1):

After sorting, we can be sure that, if x1, x2, ... xk are the solution, then x1, x2, ... xk are contiguous elements, right?

So,

1. take the intervals between numbers
2. sum these intervals to get the intervals between k numbers
3. Choose the smallest of them

Answer (score 0):

My initial solution was to look through all the K element window and multiply each element by m and take the sum in that range, where m is initialized by -(K-1) and incremented by 2 in each step and take the minimum sum from the entire list. So for a window of size 3, m is -2 and the values for the range will be -2 0 2. This is because I observed a property that each element in the K window add a certain weight to the sum. For an example if the elements are [10 20 30] the sum is (30-10) + (30-20) + (20-10). So if we break down the expression we have 2*30 + 0*20 + (-2)*10. This can be achieved in O(n) time and the entire operation would be in O(NK) time. However it turns out that this solution is not optimal, and there are certain edge cases where this algorithm fails. I am yet to figure out those cases, but shared the solution anyway if anyone can figure out something useful from it.

```
for(i = 0 ;i <= n - k;++i)
{
    diff = 0;
    l = -(k-1);
    for(j = i;j < i + k;++j)
    {
        diff += a[j]*l;
        if(min < diff)
            break;
        l += 2;
    }
    if(j == i + k && diff > 0)
    min = diff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is `O(n log n)` time with a sliding window approach (`O(n)` if the array is already sorted).

First, suppose we've precomputed, at every index `i` in our array, the sum of distances from `A[i]` to the previous `k-1` elements. The formula for that would be

`(A[i] - A[i-1]) + (A[i] - A[i-2]) + ... + (A[i] - A[i-k+1])`.

If `i` is less than `k-1`, we just compute the sum to the array boundary.

Suppose we also precompute, at every index `i` in our array, the sum of distances from `A[i]` to the next `k-1` elements. Then we could solve the whole problem with a single pass of a sliding window.

If our sliding window is on `[L, L+k-1]` with closeness sum `S`, then the closeness sum for the interval `[L+1, L+k]` is just `S - dist_sum_to_next[L] + dist_sum_to_prev[L+k]`. The only changes in the sum of pairwise distances are removing all terms involving `A[L]` when it leaves our window, and adding all terms involving `A[L+k]` as it enters our window.

The only remaining part is how to compute, at a position `i`, the sum of distances between `A[i]` and the previous `k-1` elements (the other computation is totally symmetric). If we know the distance sum at `i-1`, this is easy: subtract the distance from `A[i-1]` to `A[i-k]`, and add in the extra distance from `A[i-1]` to `A[i]` `k-1` times

```py
dist_sum_to_prev[i] =   (dist_sum_to_prev[i - 1] - (A[i - 1] - A[i - k])
                      + (A[i] - A[i - 1]) * (k - 1)
```

Python code:

```py
def closest_subset(nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
    """Given a list of n (poss. unsorted and non-unique) integers nums,
     returns a (sorted) list of size k that minimizes the sum of pairwise
     distances between all elements in the list.

     Runs in O(n lg n) time, uses O(n) auxiliary space.
    """

    n = len(nums)
    assert len(nums) == n
    assert 2 <= k <= n

    nums.sort()

    # Sum of pairwise distances to the next (at most) k-1 elements
    dist_sum_to_next = [0] * n

    # Sum of pairwise distances to the last (at most) k-1 elements
    dist_sum_to_prev = [0] * n

    for i in range(1, n):
        if i >= k:
            dist_sum_to_prev[i] = ((dist_sum_to_prev[i - 1] -
                                    (nums[i - 1] - nums[i - k]))
                                   + (nums[i] - nums[i - 1]) * (k - 1))
        else:
            dist_sum_to_prev[i] = (dist_sum_to_prev[i - 1]
                                   + (nums[i] - nums[i - 1]) * i)

    for i in reversed(range(n - 1)):
        if i < n - k:
            dist_sum_to_next[i] = ((dist_sum_to_next[i + 1]
                                    - (nums[i + k] - nums[i + 1]))
                                   + (nums[i + 1] - nums[i]) * (k - 1))
        else:
            dist_sum_to_next[i] = (dist_sum_to_next[i + 1]
                                   + (nums[i + 1] - nums[i]) * (n-i-1))

    best_sum = math.inf
    curr_sum = 0
    answer_right_bound = 0

    for i in range(n):
        curr_sum += dist_sum_to_prev[i]
        if i >= k:
            curr_sum -= dist_sum_to_next[i - k]

        if curr_sum < best_sum and i >= k - 1:
            best_sum = curr_sum
            answer_right_bound = i

    return nums[answer_right_bound - k + 1:answer_right_bound + 1]
```