# Find subset of size k such that the sum of distance between each pair of consecutive elements is minimum

Tags: sum, size, subset

Given a set *X* of *N* non-negative integers, find a subset *L* of size *K* such that the sum of distance between each pair of consecutive elements of *L* (denoted by *S(L)*) is minimum and *L* contains no duplicates. We know that `2 <= N <= 10^5`, `2 <= K < N`, *X* is unsorted and may contain duplicates.

**Note:**

2. The distance between two consecutive elements *Xi* and *Xj* (for *i* in [1, *K* - 1]; *j* in [*i* + 1, *K*]) is denoted by `d(i, j)`, which is the absolute value of the difference of *Xi* and *Xj* : `|Xj - Xi|`.
3. The relative order of elements of the original set *S* must be preserved, i.e we are **not allowed** to sort *X*. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482332/find-subset-with-k-elements-that-are-closest-to-eachother) but all of the suggested solutions require a sorting procedure.

   > **Example:**
   >
   > > **Input:**
   > >
   > > > *S* = { 1, 3, 10, 3, 6, 7, 1 }
   > > >
   > > > *K* = 4
   > >
   > > **Output:**
   > >
   > > > *L* = { 1, 3, 6, 7 } (*S(L)* = *d*(1, 2) + *d*(2, 3) + *d*(3, 4) = 2 + 3 + 1 = 6).

Notice that two sets *L1* = { 3, 6, 1, 7 } and *L* = { 1, 3, 6, 7 } are the same, but each set yields different sums (*S(L1)* = 3 + 5 + 6 = `14` > `6` = *S(L)*). Therefore, the correct sum must be the sum obtained after *L* is sorted.