# sum of absolute differences of a number in an array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I want to calculate the sum of absolute differences of a number at index i with all integers up to index i-1 in o(n). But i am not able to think of any approach better than o(n^2) .

For E.g. :

```
[3,5,6,7,1]
```

array with absolute sum will be(for integer at index i sum will be at index i in another array):

```
[0, 2, 4, 7, 17]
```

Can anyone help me to reduce the complexity to o(n) (if not possible then at least better optimization in terms of time complexity)?

Here my python code:

```
a=[3,5,6,7,1]
n=5
absoluteSumArray=[]
for i in range(0,n):
  Sum=0
  for j in range(0,i):
     Sum+=abs(int(a[i])-int(a[j]))
  absoluteSumArray.append(Sum)
```

Comment: `[sum( abs(a[i] - a[j]) for j in range(i)) for i in range(n)]` yield `[0, 2, 4, 7, 17]`

Comment: @cdhagmann Cool story, but OP already has an O(n^2) solution

Comment: "I want to calculate the sum of absolute differences of a number at index i with all integers at index i-1". But that's not what your code is doing. It's calculating the sum of absolute differences of a number at index i with all integers at indices 0 through i-1.

Comment: Does the preprocessing stage count as well?

Comment: `O(n)` looks unlikely.

Comment: Do we have any additional information or restrictions on the input?

Comment: Even a [strictly easier problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855066/finding-sum-of-absolute-difference-of-every-pair-of-integer-from-an-array) (computing the sum of the output of this problem) only got an O(nlog(n)) solution when it came up a few years back.

Comment: I think calculating "differences of a number at index i," as you state in the first sentence, can be done in O(i) time. What you mean seems to be "calculating the differences for the numbers at all indexes of the array..."

Comment: @גלעדברקן He wants to do that for all indices, faster than O(sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i) = O(n^2)

Comment: This is about the [**ADIGIT challenge**](http://www.codechef.com/APRIL14/problems/ADIGIT) on CodeChef (the input bounds are specified on that page as well). [At least three questions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=chef+and+digits) have been asked about it on Code Review. One easy way to reduce the time complexity is to add all indices to a dict, then traverse the digits, counting them and calculating each result if the index of the current digit is in the dictionary, [as shown in my answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46781/9390).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can offer an O(n log n) solution for a start: Let f<sub>i</sub> be the i-th number of the result. We have:

[image]

When walking through the array from left to right and maintain a binary search tree of the elements *a<sub>0</sub>* to  *a<sub>i-1</sub>*, we can solve all parts of the formula in O(log n):

- Keep subtree sizes to count the elements larger than/smaller than a given one
- Keep cumulative subtree sums to answer the sum queries for elements larger than/smaller than a given one

We can replace the augmented search tree with some simpler data structures if we want to avoid the implementation cost:

- Sort the array beforehand. Assign every number its rank in the sorted order
- Keep a [binary indexed tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) of 0/1 values to calculate the number of elements smaller than a given value
- Keep another binary indexed tree of the array values to calculate the sums of elements smaller than a given value

TBH I don't think this can be solved in O(n) in the general case. At the very least you would need to sort the numbers at some point. But maybe the numbers are bounded or you have some other restriction, so you might be able to implement the sum and count operations in O(1).

An implementation:

```
# binary-indexed tree, allows point updates and prefix sum queries
class Fenwick:
  def __init__(self, n):
    self.tree = [0]*(n+1)
    self.n = n
  def update_point(self, i, val):  # O(log n)
    i += 1
    while i <= self.n:
      self.tree[i] += val
      i += i & -i
  def read_prefix(self, i):        # O(log n)
    i += 1
    sum = 0
    while i > 0:
      sum += self.tree[i]
      i -= i & -i
    return sum

def solve(a):
  rank = { v : i for i, v in enumerate(sorted(a)) }
  res = []
  counts, sums = Fenwick(len(a)), Fenwick(len(a))
  total_sum = 0
  for i, x in enumerate(a):
    r = rank[x]
    num_smaller = counts.read_prefix(r)
    sum_smaller = sums.read_prefix(r)
    res.append(total_sum - 2*sum_smaller + x * (2*num_smaller - i))
    counts.update_point(r, 1)
    sums.update_point(r, x)
    total_sum += x
  return res

print(solve([3,5,6,7,1]))  # [0, 2, 4, 7, 17]
print(solve([2,0,1]))      # [0, 2, 2]
```

Comment: your too good at algorithms :P ... nice answer ... and the only right one you have convinced me

Comment: I think o(n) is not possible. But i will wait little bit(in-case) while i implement this. Thanks .

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I see no prove that it works (it seems there is a factor missing) and there is no code to try

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I just realized the missing factor as well. However, the formula arguably pretty much proves that the algorithm is correct

Comment: the next step is to prove that `fi` can be computed in sublinear time. The formula as is looks `O(i)` that is the whole algorithm is O(n**2).

Comment: @JoranBeasley What? It's O(n log n), OPs version is Omega(n^2). Obviously the constant factor is much higher for small lists. Try it with a list of size 10000 and you'll notice the difference pretty clearly

Comment: on a list of size 10k I see this algorithm get a timeit of  0.065 (for 1 iteration) , vs his old algorithm @ 15.115 (also only 1 time) ... thats a pretty awesome speedup (if your lists are large)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an `Omega(n log n)`-comparison lower bound in the linear decision tree model. This rules out the possibility of a "nice" `o(n log n)`-time algorithm (two now-deleted answers both were in this class).

There is a trivial reduction to this problem from the problem of computing

```
f(x1, ..., xn) = sum_i sum_j |xi - xj|.
```

The function `f` is totally differentiable at `x1, ..., xn` if and only if `x1, ..., xn` are pairwise distinct. The set where `f` is totally differentiable thus has `n!` connected components, of which each leaf of the decision tree can handle at most one.

Comment: Time to go learn about the capabilities of linear decision trees so I can understand this bound.