# How to find the index of a k-permutation from n elements?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I know that, for a `k`-permutation `p` of size `k`, built from `n` elements, there are:

```
P(n, k) = n! / (n - k)!
```

possible `k`-permutations. For example:

```
k = 2
n = 4
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
P(n, k) = 4! / (4 - 2)! = 12

1 2 | 2 1 | 3 1 | 4 1
1 3 | 2 3 | 3 2 | 4 2
1 4 | 2 4 | 3 4 | 4 3
```

And yet another example:

```
k = 3
n = 4
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
P(n, k) = 4! / (4 - 3)! = 24

1 2 3 | 2 1 3 | 3 1 2 | 4 1 2
1 2 4 | 2 1 4 | 3 1 4 | 4 1 3
1 3 2 | 2 3 1 | 3 2 1 | 4 2 1
1 3 4 | 2 3 4 | 3 2 4 | 4 2 3
1 4 2 | 2 4 1 | 3 4 1 | 4 3 1
1 4 3 | 2 4 3 | 3 4 2 | 4 3 2
```

So, how do I find the index of the `k`-permutation `p`? Consider the permutations
to be generated lexicographically.

**Edit**:
I could start by finding in which "block" `p` is, addressing the block by the first element of `p`. For example, for `p = [3, 2, 4]`, the index for `p` should be at least 12 (counting from 0 to `P(n, k) - 1`).

But then, to find the second element inside that "block", I'd have to see what are the remaining items to be found, and in which position they will be. I mean, I'd be eventually addressing the list `[1, 4]`, and 4 would be at position 2, so simply using the element as key would require some extra manipulation.

I could use a hash to look up the elements and update their positions, but it'd give me a `O(n^2)` time complexity. Is it possible to do any better?

Comment: Possible starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code#Encoding_and_decoding

Comment: @Kaz Thanks very much for the reference. I'll check it out, and I'll also try to use TXR. I was thinking about introducing myself to Lisp, and now I'm going to try both Lisp and TXR. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of permutations for a given digit in a given position is given by a formula
(n-digit position)! / (n-k)! where digit position starts on the left with 1.

To get the number of preceding permutations for a given permutation (that is, its index), multiply the formula for each digit by the number of preceding digits not already used, and add them up.

Example 1, k = 2, n = 4, p = [3,4]

First digit, 3: 
(4-1)! / (4-2)! * (number of unused preceding digits, 2) = 6
There are six permutations preceding the first that has 3 in position 1.

Second digit, 4: 
(4-2)! / (4-2)! * (number of unused preceding digits, 2) = 2
There are two permutations preceding the first that has 4 in position 2.

Zero based index: 6 + 2 = 8.

Example 2, k = 3, n = 4, p = [3,2,4]

First digit, 3: 
(4-1)! / (4-3)! * (number of unused preceding digits, 2) = 12
There are 12 permutations preceding the first that has 3 in position 1.

Second digit, 2: 
(4-2)! / (4-3)! * (number of unused preceding digits, 1) = 2
There are two permutations preceding the first that has 2 in position 2.

Third digit, 4: 
(4-3)! / (4-3)! * (number of unused preceding digits, 1) = 1
There is one permutation preceding the first that has 4 in position 3.

Zero based index: 12 + 2 + 1 = 15.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! Awesome solution indeed! Thanks for teaching me that! :D

Comment: Although at first I thought this would be linear, even in its worst case, now I guess it's more than that. What is the time complexity of your *number of unused preceding digits* function? Unless it's made constant, the worst case would be either logarithmic (using some binary search structure) or linear. I can't think of any approach to keep a *table of unused preceding digits* in `O(1)`. Can you think of any solution for that?

Comment: @Rubens That is another interesting question. Let me think about it. How big could `n` be?

Comment: Actually `n` is reasonably *small*, being 25 my current maximum. Despite of the size, which I guess may help yielding some language-specific solution (like using bit count in c/c++), I've got very curious about whether it was possible to derive that method in `O(1)`. Glad to see you're interested too! :D

Comment: With a maximum of 25 for `n`, it seems to me that bit-counting should be very fast. In general, I cannot come up with a solution for the number of unused preceding digits that is not exponential in time-complexity, in relation to `n`. I'm not too much of an expert, though.

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943787/sum-of-absolute-differences-of-a-number-in-an-array/22944263#22944263

Answer (score 2):

[TXR language](http://www.nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr -p "(pos '(1 4 3) (perm '(1 2 3 4) 3))"
5
```

It is brute force, however; of course `pos` knows nothing about the structure of permutations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please, check my edit. I *forgot* to add what I had thought of so far, and what *exactly* I was looking for as an answer.

Comment: Yes; you're looking for a fast algorithm, rather than just any old code to spit out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (BST). Store all you numbers in it before you start and delete them after you use one. To find x-th element maintain `.subtreeSize` for every vertex and just descend the tree to find the number you need. Pseudocode:

```
    def findXth(x):
        curVertex = BST.root
        while:
            curPosition = curVertex.leftChild.subtreeSize
            if curPosition == x: return curVertex.value
            elif curPosition > x: curVertex = curVertex.leftChild
            elif curPosition < x: curVertex = curVertex.rightChild
```

Don't forget to check for vertices existence and to delete the vertex you find.

Overall complexity is going to be O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

you can reference below function

```
 /**
 *  list all k or <=k size permutation of a given list with n unique elements.
 *  n can be bigger than 64. this function will take O(K^N) time, Bad.
 *
 * @param uniqueList
 * @param permutationSize
 * @param permutation
 * @param only            Only show the permutation of permutationSize,
 *                        else show all permutation of less than or equal to permutationSize.
 */
public static void my_permutationOf(List<Integer> uniqueList, int permutationSize, List<Integer> permutation, boolean only) {
    if (permutation == null) {
        assert 0 < permutationSize && permutationSize <= uniqueList.size();
        permutation = new ArrayList<>(permutationSize);
        if (!only) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permutation.toArray()));
        }
    }
    for (int i : uniqueList) {
        if (permutation.contains(i)) {
            continue;
        }
        permutation.add(i);
        if (!only) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permutation.toArray()));
        } else if (permutation.size() == permutationSize) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permutation.toArray()));
        }
        if (permutation.size() < permutationSize) {
            my_permutationOf(uniqueList, permutationSize, permutation, only);
        }
        permutation.remove(permutation.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

E.g.  you can think the element is the index

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    my_permutationOf(new ArrayList<Integer>() {
        {
            add(0);
            add(1);
            add(2);
            add(3);

        }
    }, 3, null, true);
}
```

the result is

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 3, 1]
[0, 3, 2]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 3]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 0]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 3]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 0]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 0, 1]
[3, 0, 2]
[3, 1, 0]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 0]
[3, 2, 1]
```