# Simplify calculating difference between every element and the elements to its right

Tags: loops, for-loop, nested

Can I make it Simpler ?

```
 for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
 for(int l=(k+1);l<n;l++)
 {
     tot+=(max(a[k],a[l])-min(a[k],a[l]));
 }
```

this program is currently taking more time to execute and exceeding the time limit.

Comment: just how big is `n`? And what exactly are you trying to accomplish. Trying to optimize this code is pointless without knowing what you want to end up with. Maybe you're going about this ENTIRELY wrong and there's something far simpler to get what you want.

Comment: it should be in C++.

Comment: You can replace `max(a[k],a[l])-min(a[k],a[l])` with something like `abs(a[k] - a[l])`. For more improvements we need to know what you actually want

Comment: I trying to check the difference b/w all 2 elements of an array a[n] and that too positive values only i.e y i gave: (max(a[k],a[l])-min(a[k],a[l])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding sum of Absolute Difference of Every pair of integer from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855066/finding-sum-of-absolute-difference-of-every-pair-of-integer-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly simpler version:

```
var k = -1,
    l, tot

while(++k < n){
  l = k
  while(++l < n){
    tot += Math.abs(a[k] - a[l])
  }
}
```

It's also possible to get the same functionality very succinctly with es6 syntax, though I'm not sure which version is quicker performance-wise. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhcsk8gn/5/) with the two methods side by side.

```
"use strict";
var a = [3, 22, 12, 99, 1, 6, 19];
var test = a.reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
  return previousValue + a.reduce((pv, cv, ci, arr) => {
    return ci > currentIndex ? pv + Math.abs(cv - currentValue) : pv
  }, 0)
}, 0)
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are trying to calculate the difference between every element and all elements to the right of it. What you could do is calculate the sum of the whole array, then each time you move from one element to the next subtract that particular number from the total and the total difference would now just be total sum - current element.

```
// Sort the array 'a' first and then run this.
int sum = calculateSum() // Write this method yourself to find total
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    sum -= a[i];
    tot += (sum - a[i] * (n - i + 1));
}
```

The last line subtracts from the sum the total differences by taking into account the number of times you would have ideally subtracted the element in consideration.