# Finding product of Absolute Difference of Every pair of integer from an array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array, find the product of the absolute difference of every pair of integers.

For example: Given **a[]= {2,3, 5, 7 };**

output would be **(3-2) * (5-2) * (7-2) * (5-3) * (7-3) * (7-5) = 240**.

Can it be done better than O(n^2) ?
**Edit:**
All elements are distinct.

Comment: Seems unlikely since the number of factors itself is O(n^2)... unless there exists some wild reformulation for that expression.

Comment: I have written code by making use of two loops. In which outer loop goes from 0 to n-2 and inner loop goes from 1 to n-1. I keep one variable product for tracking current product of elements-In which I find absolute difference of element[ i ] and element [j] and multiply it to product variable. After loops end, I print product variable.

Comment: @ManojBanik I don't think there is need to put my code in question. As it will not help to think about solution better than O(n^2). Since I have mentioned that my code has complexity O(n^2), It is clear what approach I have used.

Comment: Note: this is clearly related to the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix. But I can't see how to use it to get a faster calculation.

Answer (score 0):

**If you had to compute the sum of the absolute differences, then this would be your solution**

Basically, if you take an arbitrary number, let's name it x, then you have it

m * x - n * x,

where m is the number of items which are smaller than x and n is the n number of items, which are greater than x. So, if for some reason you had a sorted array, then the index of each item would directly tell you how many greater or smaller items are if it's unique in the array. If not, then you can determine the number of higher and lower elements as well.

So, if the array is sorted, than computing the result is linear. Sorting the array if it's completely unsorted is n * log(n) of complexity if you use mergesort. Hence, the complexity is

O(n + n * log(n)) = (n + 1)log(n)

**But for the product of absolute differences**

you have a product of the form of

(a1 - b1) * ... (...)

since you have a product of subtractions, in order to find a pattern that you could use to optimize, you need more information about your data. The input that you have seem to contain primes. The product of

(a1 - b1) * (a2 - b2)

is

a1a2 - a1b2 - b1a2 + b1b2

I do not know about any pattern that you could use for your optimization, so I think this has an O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you use this to compute the result? I understand that the sorted position of an element gives you the number of smaller and greater elements, but how do you go from there to the result? Note the absolute differences are multiplied, not summed.

Comment: @jdehesa my answer solves the issue of summing them up and your point is spot on, I solved something else than the asker asked for. Thinking about the real problem and will either edit or remove this answer.

Comment: FTR, the modified problem is a duplicate of: [Finding sum of Absolute Difference of Every pair of integer from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5855066/572670) :)

Comment: @amit Yes It is inspired from that question. As I had recently visited that question, I thought if I can do product instead of sum with complexity better than O(n^2).